# Sum amount base from previous value on slicer power bi

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a table like this:

```
Year        Month       Code     Amount
---------------------------------------   
2017        11           a        7368    
2017        11           b        3542    
2017        12           a        4552    
2017        12           b        7541    
2018         1           a        6352    
2018         1           b        8376    
2018         2           a        1287    
2018         2           b        3625
```

I make slicer base on Year and Month (ignore the Code), and I want to show SUM of Amount like this :

- If I select on slicer `Year 2017 and Month 12`, the value to be shown is SUM Amount base on 2017-11, and select on slicer `Year 2018 and Month 1` should be SUM Amount base on 2017-12

I have tried this one for testing with, but this not allowed:

```
Last Month = CALCULATE(SUM(Table[Amount]); Table[Month] = SELECTEDVALUE(Table[Month]) - 1)
```

How to do it right?

I want something like this

[image: https://ibb.co/eGJTce]

NB: I use direct query to SQL Server

Update: At this far, I added `Last_Amount` column in SQL Server Table by sub-query, maybe you guys have a better way for my issue

Comment: You should also show us what the expected output looks like.  The logic is not entirely clear to me, just based on your description.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i can't upload picture yet, but maybe it will looks like this https://ibb.co/eGJTce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filters in a `CALCULATE` statement are only designed to take simple statements that don't have further calculations involved. There are a couple of possible remedies.

**1.** Use a variable to compute the previous month number before you use it in the `CALCULATE` function.

```
Last Month = 
    VAR PrevMonth = SELECTEDVALUE(Table[Month]) - 1
    RETURN CALCULATE(SUM(Table[Amount]), Table[Month] = PrevMonth)
```

**2.** Use a `FILTER()` function. This is an iterator that allows more complex filtering.

```
Last Month = CALCULATE(SUM(Table[Amount]),
                 FILTER(ALL(Table),
                     Table[Month] = SELECTEDVALUE(Table[Month]) - 1))
```

---

**Edit:** Since you are using year and month, you need to have a special case for January.

```
Last Month = 
    VAR MonthFilter = MOD(SELECTEDVALUE(Table[Month]) - 2, 12) + 1
    VAR YearFilter = IF(PrevMonth = 12,
                         SELECTEDVALUE(Table[Year]) - 1,
                         SELECTEDVALUE(Table[Year]))
    RETURN CALCULATE(SUM(Table[Amount]),
               Table[Month] = MonthFilter,
               Table[Year] = YearFilter)
```

Comment: that bring the month 1 to 0. i should make calculation in year too if the selectedvalue is 1. that's possible to calculate with that condition? the FILTER function didn't work in direct query mode, I've tried that one.

Comment: that awesome! thank you very much Alexis for helping me :)